# Release cron lock

Tags: 8, cron

I ran cron and aborted the execution. Now I get this message:

> Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running.

In Drupal 7, I could delete the  *cron_semaphore* variable.

What's the way to achieve the same in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's now in the `semaphore` table with the key name "cron". This can be removed via

```bash
drush sqlq "DELETE FROM semaphore WHERE name = 'cron';"
```

Or, if you can execute PHP in Drupal bootstrapped environment, you can run the line:

```php
\Drupal::lock()->release('cron');
```

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to [Shawns answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/203103/4266)..

```
drush php-eval "\Drupal::lock()->release('cron');"
```

Seemed to help!

Comment: Does not work (D8.8.5).

Comment: It didn't work for me either, but then I tried `drush php-eval "\Drupal::lock()->acquire('cron', 10);"` first a couple of times and finally could call `drush php-eval "\Drupal::lock()->release('cron');"` to release the stuck lock

Comment: drush sqlq "DELETE FROM semaphore WHERE name = 'cron';" works

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get it to work in Drupal 8 with the suggested steps from above - perhaps you are using something like Redis and the cron lock is stored there. In this case you can progress with:

```
drush php-eval '\Drupal::service("lock")->release("all")'
```

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 doesn't anymore uses the *cron_semaphore* variable, but a lock. See [`drupal_cron_run()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7.x), and in particular the following lines, part of that function.

```
// Try to acquire cron lock.
if (!lock_acquire('cron', 240.0)) {
  // Omissis
}
```

```
// Release cron lock.
lock_release('cron');
```

Porting those lines to Drupal 8 is quite straight, since Drupal 8 has a service for getting and releasing a lock.

The equivalent code is in [`Cron::run()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cron.php/function/Cron%3A%3Arun/8.5.x).

```
// Try to acquire cron lock.
if (!$this->lock->acquire('cron', 900.0)) {
  // Omissis
}
```

```
// Release cron lock.
$this->lock->release('cron');
```

If you need to unlock it in a host where you cannot use Drush, as it happens to me, to achieve the same from an external script that bootstraps Drupal would require code similar to the following one.

```
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Drupal\Core\Site\Settings;

chdir('..');

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

function cron_unlock_access_allowed(Request $request) {
  $account = \Drupal::service('authentication')->authenticate($request);
  if ($account) {
    \Drupal::currentUser()->setAccount($account);
  }
  return \Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer site configuration');
}

try {
  $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
  $kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
  $kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);
}
catch (HttpExceptionInterface $e) {
  $response = new Response('', $e->getStatusCode());
  $response->prepare($request)->send();
  exit;
}

\Drupal::moduleHandler()->addModule('system', 'core/modules/system');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->addModule('user', 'core/modules/user');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->load('system');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->load('user');

if (cron_unlock_access_allowed($request)) {
  \Drupal::lock()->release('cron');
  $status_code = 200;
}
else {
  $status_code = 403;
}
$response = new Response('', $status_code);
$response->prepare($request)->send();
```

I adapted the code of [authorize.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21authorize.php/8.5.x). I changed the user permission required to run the script, which I placed in the directory containing the authorize.php file, in the cron_cleanup.php file.

If you can run Drush, it gets easier. (See [@dman's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/213038/199).)

Answer (score 0):

I got to this error when the Drupal 7 installation stuck. I fixed it by using `drush php-eval "drupal_cron_cleanup()"`.

Comment: The question is for Drupal 8, not Drupal 7. Furthermore, in Drupal 7 that function is marked deprecated.

Comment: In fact, Drupal 7 itself uses `lock_release('cron')` to release the cron lock.

Answer (score 0):

In **Drupal 8.9.x** - I tried the below Drush commands & manually deleted the semaphore table. But, nothing is happening.

```
drush sqlq "DELETE FROM semaphore WHERE name = 'cron';"

  drush php:eval '\Drupal::lock()->release("cron");'
  drush php-eval "\Drupal::lock()->release('cron');"
  drush php-eval '\Drupal::service("lock")->release("all")'
    
  DELETE FROM semaphore WHERE name = 'cron';

  drush php-eval "\Drupal::lock()->acquire('cron', 10);" 
  I ran first a couple of times and then I did 
  drush php-eval "\Drupal::lock()->release('cron');"
```

Finally I got the Solution. Run individual cron jobs with Drush. I ran the command one by one. then it works.

```
drush php-eval "webform_cron();"
drush php-eval "update_cron();" 
drush php-eval "system_cron();" 
drush php-eval "statistics_cron();"
drush php-eval "node_cron();"
drush php-eval "locale_cron();" 
drush php-eval "history_cron();" 
drush php-eval "file_cron();" 
drush php-eval "field_cron();" 
drush php-eval "dblog_cron();" 
drush php-eval "comment_cron();
```